# Beautiful soup do not decoding part of html page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, unicode, web-crawler

Beautiful Soup returns part of html tags like `"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043b\u043e\u0436\"`.
How it could be solved?

Problem with page https://life.com.by/

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
result = requests.get('https://life.com.by/company/news')
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

it returns

```
var engTranslations = {"test":"test","or":"or","main_page":"Main Page","consultant":"Consultant","android_description":"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043b\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0434\u043b\u044f\u00a0\u0441\u043c\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0444\u043e\u043d\u043e\u0432 \u0438\u00a0\u043f\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0448\u0435\u0442\u043e\u0432 \u043d\u0430\u00a0Android","apple_description":"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043b\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0434\u043b\u044f\u00a0\u0441\u043c\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0444\u043e\u043d\u043e\u0432 \u0438\u00a0\u043f\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0448\u0435\u0442\u043e\u0432 \u043d\u0430\u00a0iOS","tv_description":"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043b\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0434\u043b\u044f\u00a0Android\u00a0TV","notebook_description":"\u0421\u043c\u043e\u0442\u0440\u0435\u0442\u044c \u0432\u00a0\u0431\u0440\u0430\u0443\u0437\u0435\u0440\u0435","new_sim":"New SIM-card","add_traffic":"Add traffic","change_tariff":"\u0421\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c \u0442\u0430\u0440\u0438\u0444\u043d\u044b\u0439\u00a0\u043f\u043b\u0430\u043d","tariff_changing":"\u0421\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0430 \u0442\u0430\u0440\u0438\u0444\u0430","for_a_day":"For a day","for_a_week":"For a week","for_a_month":"For a month","connect":"Activate","call_back_me":"\u041f\u0435\u0440\u0435\
```

If I just print part of it, it returns human - readed string.

```
print('\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043b\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435\u043f\u043e\u043c\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043c')
```

`Приложение поможем`

Comment: it doesn't return that. what you showed is the content of a `script` tag that contains javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand what you want...
But from what I understood, try this:

```
soup.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode-escape')
```